# How to display part of a UIView at the back of a view hierarchy in a UIView towards the front

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I have a `UIImageView` on my storyboard that displays an image that takes up the entire screen with aspect fill. Then on top of that I have a large `UIView` that is centered on screen called middleView. I am wondering how I can add custom `UIViews` on screen that will display the back `UIImageView`, but will only display the portion that they cover. The effect I am wanting is for the custom `UIViews` to make it look like the large centered `UIView` middleView has holes in it. Also I need for the front custom UIViews to be transformable so that the image inside them is always what is on the back imageView at their current position.

Final note: The image for the back `UIImageView` will always be the same so I don't necessarily need it to know what the back `UIImageView` is. The imageView will always be initialized with the same UIImage, start at the origin, and fill the screen with an aspect fill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The effect I am wanting is for the custom UIViews to make it look like the large centered UIView middleView has holes in it

It would be a lot simpler, surely, if the UIView middleView really *did* have holes in it. This is easily achieved with a layer mask.

For example, this image of Venus has two square holes in it, revealing an angry-looking dude from a Stack Overflow ad behind it:

[image]

Comment: As I demonstrate, for example, here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23452614/341994 The hole I made is a square, but in fact it can be any shape you like. And of course you can have more than one hole.

Comment: How would I add multiple masks. I need to have around 20 of these holes and when I use this method, only the last hole is punched in middleView.

Comment: Right - you only get one mask on a layer, but that mask can describe multiple holes.

Comment: So how do I do this? When I try and add holes the inverse happens and instead of cutting out holes it determines what isn't cut out.

Comment: Did you look at the code I pointed you to? You really don't see how to add more holes to that code?

Comment: Ok sorry - I was overcomplicating it - I figured it out. Thanks for your help.