# iOS bringSubviewToFront create a transparent square Frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to create in my App something like that:

[image]

I can open the camera and add the background 50% grey but the problem I have now, is how I can create a transparent square over the background and put in the middle a red line.

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.background];
```

If I add the next line appear the square but appear the background.

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.transparentSquare];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `self.background` is too simple. It is solid gray, so it appears as solid gray even behind your transparent square. You need to "punch a hole" in `self.background` so that it is transparent at the place where the transparent square will go. You can easily do that with a mask.

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23452614/341994 for more detail about how to punch a rectangular hole in a view using a mask.

Comment: Works perfect!, about the: CGRect r2 = CGRectMake(20,20,40,40);for use with several devices like iphone 5 or 6... is proportional or I have to implement a control to calculate de size of the screen?

Comment: What I would do is: use auto layout to position the transparent square. After layout, you know where the transparent square is. Now use that info to figure out where to position the hole in the mask. This will need to change every time the transparent square changes its position, obviously.

Comment: I follow your idea, and I put in the center the transparent square and assign in the code...but I was testing with several triggers like: viewWillAppear, viewDidLoad, to get the position of the transparent square with CGRect r2 = self.transparentLayout.bounds;, but the problem is that position is not set up yet, what is the trigger I can use, to get the final position with AutoLayout?