# How could we possibly create this ui concept?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uikit, calayer, uibezierpath

I came across this UI Concept, I couldnt help but to admire it's beauty.

I am wondering if it is possible to create a Button that makes (mask) the control below them, to make them look transparent in that area. (In this case UITextField)

Please take a look at this image below

[image: Cool UI Concept]

ANy idea if this is possible to be done via code?
Please look at how the button makes the UITextField become transparent with margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do it exactly the way you just said - with a *mask*. A mask attached to a layer (or view) can make a hole through that view and its subviews. In this case, that hole is a circle.

Here's an example: two UITextFields, in a view whose mask cuts a circular hole at the end of them:

[image]

I didn't add the checkmark image but that's just more of the same.

Comment: Any sample code or links please? Thank you for your responsive reply

Comment: For example, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23452614/341994

Comment: Added an example image.

Comment: @matt thats perfect!! thanks for being so helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and simple example of how you can create such UI cocept with CSS3:

```css
.inputfield {
 width: 300px;
 height: 50px;
 line-height: 40px;
 padding: 8px;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: 6px solid #000;
}
span.okcircle {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 6px solid #fff;
 background: #DF01A5;
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 margin-top: 24px;
 margin-left: 270px;
 z-index: 9;
 position: absolute; 

}
```

```html
<span class="okcircle"> </span>
<div><input type="text" placeholder="username" class="inputfield"></div>
<div><input type="password" placeholder="password" class="inputfield"></div>
```

Here's the output: 
[image]

Comment: it's just a quick example. You can modify it further to add `border-radius` around `input` elements and also you can add icons and other stuff later..