# CGRectIntersection setting colour

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cgcontext

I'm using this code here to create a view with a transparent area.

https://github.com/heigong/PartialTransparentMaskView/blob/master/src/PartialTransparentMaskView.swift

The issue is that the intersection is black even though the colour is set to  `UIColor.clearColour()`

My code for creating this view is below

```
let view = PartialTransparentMaskView(frame: self.view.bounds, backgroundColor: UIColor.blueColor(), transparentRects: [self.testView.frame], transparentCircles: nil)
self.view.addSubview(view)
```

How this looks is also below

[image]

The area in the black is set to `UIColor.clearColor()` so I genuinely have no idea why it would be appearing black.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Because the view is `opaque`, probably. But I don't know this third party code you're using, and punching a hole in a view is so easy that I wouldn't use one.

Comment: The super view or ```let view```?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know because that's not how I would do it. I would just put a mask on the view.

Comment: I tried to use masks originally but I couldn't get the effect I was going for. Would you possibly know how I could achieve this effect by setting the mask?

Comment: What is the desired "effect"? Just punch a rectangular hole? Look up terms like "mask" and "hole". See for example my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23452614/341994 And see my book if you don't know what a mask is: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch16.html#_shadows_borders_and_more